# What is an elegant way to convert a boolean array into increasing numerical array?

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following array:

```
jump = array([[False, False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

What is an elegant way to map this array to a numerical array that increases by +1 each time a 'True' is encountered?
Like so:

```
[0,0,1,1,1,2].
```

This does work:

```
cat = np.zeros([6,])

it = 0
for i in range(0,np.shape(jumps)[0]):
    if jumps[i] == True:
        it = it + 1
    cat[i] = it
```

However this method uses a for loop which is notorious to be slower than (for example) matrix calculations. Is there a way to apply this function without the for loop, e.i. in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) seems appropriate here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.cumsum([False, False,  True, False, False,  True])
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Fortunately bool is a subclass of int, so performing arithmetic on them in this way is possible.